# Google Analytics event tracking dependent on source of visit

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am looking to test different traffic patterns within Google Analytics (Direct traffic abnormally high).  I was curious if anyone knows how to create an event that fires when source =wildcard  To make this event more difficult, this would be set up within Google Tag Manager using Universal Analytics.

I see the 6 event tags but none of them sounds like it would perform my need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager is not a tracking tool and knows nothing about the traffic source, so no preconfigured macro could be used in a rule to fire tags depending on source.

If you use "classic" asynchronous analytics you can set up a macro that reads the _utmz-cookie and checks in a rule if it contains a source string ("direct","cpc" etc.).

However Universal Analytics determines the traffic source on the server and does not store it clientside, so with UA this would not work.

A few traffic sources are easily recognizable on the respective landing page:

- If no referrer is present it's a direct visit/bookmark
- if there are campaign (utm) parameters in the url you can use those
- if there is a gclid parameter in the url you know it google/cpc
- if the referrer is a google domain with a country tld and the parameter "q" is present (will be empty with encrypted search but should still be there) it's an organic google search
- if the referrer is a bing domain with the parameter q present it's an organic bing search (and similar for other search engines)

However this will only work on landing pages. You need to write you own cookie to store the source for subsequent pages.

You can refine this approach to give rather similar results to Google Analytics but it will never match perfectly.

One of the most common reasons for abnormal high direct traffic is that no campaign parameters are present in paid traffic, either because you forgot to enable autotagging in your adwords campaigns or because you have redirects that strip out campaign parameters (so paid traffic is lumped together with direct).  The above approach would not help you to discover this so I suggest you check this manually first before you do anything else.